# Tell HTML5 Video tag to wait with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, html5-video

I have a video streaming server in NodeJS written with express. The HTML file has this video tag:

```html
<video id="videoPlayer" width="600" controls muted="muted" autoplay>
  <source src="/vidChunk?id=Demo1" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I'm trying to implement bit rate control by limiting the number of requests that go through. Once the page exceeds a certain rate I want to send back a wait command, but I can't seem to find something to send back that doesn't error out and freeze. Usually, I send content over with a 206 (partial data), and I've tried sending a 503 with retry headers, I've tried sending a 409. Does anyone know what the video tag will accept as a wait command?

Comment: What exactly does _“error out and freeze”_ and how?

Comment: Chrome shows a 503 or 409 error then stops asking for requests from the server, therefor making it freeze